# Is the format/structure of SciPy's condensed distance matrix stable?

Tags: python, data-structures, scipy

Several SciPy functions are documented as taking a "condensed distance matrix as returned by `scipy.spatial.distance.pdist`". Now, inspection shows that what `pdist` returns is the row-major 1D-array form of the upper off-diagonal part of the distance matrix. This is all well and good, and natural and obvious, but is it documented or defined anywhere? I'd rather not assume anything about a data structure that'll suddenly change. (Granted, there isn't a lot of things it could change to, but I guess one possibility would be to wrap the array in an object that allows matrix-like indexing.)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Honestly, this is a better question for the scipy users or dev list, as it's about future plans for scipy.

However, the structure is fairly rigorously documented in the docstrings for both `scipy.spatial.pdist` and in `scipy.spatial.squareform`.

E.g. for `pdist`:

```
Returns a condensed distance matrix Y.  For
    each :math:`i` and :math:`j` (where :math:`i<j<n`), the
    metric ``dist(u=X[i], v=X[j])`` is computed and stored in the
    :math:`ij`th entry.

    See ``squareform`` for information on how to calculate the index of
    this entry or to convert the condensed distance matrix to a
    redundant square matrix.
```

Becuase of this, and the fact that so many other functions in `scipy.spatial` expect a distance matrix in this form, I'd seriously doubt it's going to change without a number of depreciation warnings and announcements.

Modules in `scipy` itself (as opposed to scipy's `scikits`) are fairly stable, and there's a great deal of consideration put into backwards compatibility when changes are made (and because of this, there's quite a bit of legacy "cruft" in `scipy`: e.g. the fact that the core `scipy` module is just numpy with different defaults on a couple of functions.).

Comment: Thanks! I agree that the question is more suited for the scipy mailing list, but the kind of answer you give here is certainly sufficient, and sort of what I was hoping for.